# Laravel5.5のLoginController内でオーバーライドしたattemptLoginにフォームリクエストのインスタンスが渡せない

Tags: laravel-5

Laravel5.5においてid、メールアドレス両方でログインできるように
ログインフォームのカスタマイズを行っていて、ログイン時にバリデーションをかけるため `app\Http\Requests\UserRequest` を作り、 `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` でuseしています。

LoginControllerでは `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php` のattemptLoginをオーバーライドしてUserRequestを渡しているのですが下記のようなエラーが出てうまくいきません。

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::attemptLogin() must be an instance of app\Http\Requests\UserRequest, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /vagrant/exapmle.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 42

LoginControllerは下記のようにしております。

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Http\Requests\UserRequest;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'login';
    }

    protected function attemptLogin(UserRequest $request)
    {

dd($request);
//省略
    }
}
```

UserRequestは

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(Request $request)
    {
        if (filter_var($request->login, \FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return [
                'login' => 'required|max:30',
                'password' => 'required|between:6,20',
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'login' => 'required|between:6,20',
                'password' => 'required|between:6,20',
            ];
        }

    }


    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            // 省略
        ];
    }


    protected function failedValidation( Validator $validator)
    {
        $response['data']    = [];
        $response['status']  = 'NG';
        $response['summary'] = 'Failed validation.';
        $response['errors']  = $validator->errors()->toArray();

        throw new HttpResponseException(
            response()->json( $response, 422 )
        );
    }

}
```

検索してみたのですが同じようなケースが見つかりませんでした。
マルチログインでadminも作ったのですがAdminLoginController内でAdminRequestをuseした場合はうまく動作しました。デフォルトで用意されているLoginControllerの場合はうまくいかないのでしょうか？
ご教授頂けませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 自己解決しました。
`
    public function login(UserRequest $request)
    {
        $username = $request->input($this->username());
        $password = $request->input('password');

        if (filter_var($username, \FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $credentials = ['email' => $username, 'password' => $password];
        } else {
            $credentials = [$this->username() => $username, 'password' => $password];
        }

        if ( Auth::guard()->attempt($credentials , $request->remember)) {
            return $credentials;
        }
        // 省略
    }
`

Comment: attemptLoginメソッドは利用しないでloginメソッドをオーバーライドすることでうまくいきました。

Comment: 自己解決された場合以下の回答欄にお願いします

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

```
public function login(UserRequest $request)
{
    $username = $request->input($this->username());
    $password = $request->input('password');
    if (filter_var($username, \FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $credentials = ['email' => $username, 'password' => $password];
    } else { 
        $credentials = [$this->username() => $username, 'password' => $password];
    }
    if ( Auth::guard()->attempt($credentials , $request->remember)) {
        return $credentials;
    }
    // 省略
}
```

attemptLoginメソッドは利用しないでloginメソッドをオーバーライドすることでうまくいきました。